# geographically weighted negative binomial regression in R

Tags: r, regression, gwr, gwmodel

I have read some references that related to Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) and I found that some of GWR techniques are available in R such as inside the package of GWModel.

Although there are some GWR types in there including Poisson family (GWPR), I would like to do an WGR with the Negative Binomial distribution, also called GWNBR. Unfortunately, this technique isn't available in GWModel package. Does someone know how to do an GWNBR analysis in R?

Comment: See if these help, https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/44975_0342ec49f925426fa16ebcdc28210118.html https://crd230.github.io/gwr.html